# SWR fetch doesn't return data - nextJS

Tags: next.js, fetch, swr

I have data like this and it works well

```
const datafunction = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.post('API', {
                Body Arguments
            },
                {
                    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token },
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                }
            )
            return result.data
        }
        catch (error) {
            return null
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        datafunction()
    }, [])
```

I want to catch the data, so i decided use SWR.

I am beginner in SWR and it confused me, and i could not understand SWR documents well.

Is this true?

```
const fetcher = (API,body,token) =>
    axios
      .post(API, body, { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token } })
      .then((res) => res.data);

// and put data like this
  const { data} = useSWR([`API`,body,header] , fetcher)
```

Please tell me the right structure.